# Setting default url on Safari Launcher

Tags: testing

When I run automation on appium on ios12 then browser default navigate to url (appium.io). And next navigate to URL that I had assigned. At this step, driver error appearance. How I can fix them. Have I can remove navigate to appium.io when run automation (setting on Safari Launcher app) or any soluton

> (err_0038)Error Message:An unknown server-side error occurred while
>   processing the command. Original error: Did not get any response after
>   300s